# Play HTML5 background video forward and backward with the mouse cursor

Tags: android, html, video, desktop, playback

**Hi everyone!** What I want:

I have a background video (duration 2 sec) on the homepage. Video should be played from the middle forward when the mouse cursor moves to the right and backward when the mouse cursor moves to the left. And is it possible to implement the same only on Android/iPhone? To play the video when the Android/iPhone is tilted. Maybe someone knows the examples. Please attach links to the examples.

Comment: Please take a look around the site (start with Help) and see if you can ask an appropriate question with supporting code and any error messages. I didn't down vote your question, but you can see that it is already being done by others.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Hopefully you've had a look around and seen some examples of the sorts of questions people ask here, and how they ask them. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you get help (without the downvotes)

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at `deviceOrientation` - https://caniuse.com/#search=deviceorientation

Based on that you can use code similar to below to track the movement (in this case I think it would be the `beta`, though per CanIUse you should note Safari and Chrome use different coordinate systems) to determine where in the video you want to scroll to

```
<body>

<div id="status">Loading...</div>
<div id="alpha"></div>
<div id="beta"></div>
<div id="gamma"></div>

<script>
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientationHandler, false);
    document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Supported!";
} else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support Device Orientation");
}


function deviceOrientationHandler(event) {
    var time = new Date();
    showTime = ("0" + time.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + time.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + time.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("status").innerText = "triggered: " +  showTime
    document.getElementById("alpha").innerText = "Alpha: " + Math.round(event.alpha)
    document.getElementById("beta").innerText = "Beta: " + Math.round(event.beta)
    document.getElementById("gamma").innerText = "Gamma: " + Math.round(event.gamma)
}
</script>

</body>
```